# JavaScript/jQuery: How to run DataTables after a Bootstrap modal is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, bootstrap-modal

I have the code below. In Chrome, 90% of the time, it shows a modal, the datatables is run and then when it's loaded, the modal disappears.

Any idea why it doesn't do it 100% of the time? In IE 10+ it's closer to 1% of the time.

Is there a neater way of doing this?

I basically want to show a modal first and foremost and after the data has finished loading, for the dialog to go.

When I was using AJAX with DataTables, the processing message would show but now it doesn't - is there a way to show this using the method I have below?

```
var bonza = this;

$('#vehicle_modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {

    $('#vehicle tfoot th.search_on_this').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );

    var dataSet = JSON.parse(bonza.data.js.vehicleData);
    var table = $('#vehicle').DataTable(
    {
        data: dataSet,
        processing: true,
        'language':{ 
          "loadingRecords": "Please wait whilst the table is being populated with data",
           "processing": "Please wait whilst the table is being populated with data"
        },
        "pageLength": 50,
        "scrollY": 300,
        "scrollX": true,
        "order": [[ 12, "desc" ]],
        //"autoWidth": false,
        "columnDefs": [
            //{ "width": "75px", "targets": [0,1,3,4] },
            { "width": "150px", "targets": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21] },
            //{ "width": "200px", "targets": [6,7] },
            { "targets": [ 22,23 ],"visible": false, "searchable": true
        }
        ],
        "createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {

            $('td', row).eq(12).addClass('border-right');
            $('td', row).eq(15).addClass('border-right');
            $('td', row).eq(18).addClass('border-right');

            if ( data[12] > 53) {
                $(row).addClass("red");
            }

            if ( data[12] > 21 && data[12] < 54) {
                $(row).addClass("orange");
            }
        },
         "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
            var id = aData[22];
            $(nRow).attr("data-vehicle-id", id);
            return nRow;
        }
        ,
        initComplete: function () {
            $('#vehicle_modal').modal('hide')
            this.api().columns([0,1,6,9]).every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
            $('#vehicle').DataTable().columns.adjust()
        }
    }
    );


    $('#vehicle tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var id = $(this).data("vehicle-id");
        var left = (screen.width/2)-(900/2);
        return window.open('/app/account/vehicle-edit/id/'+id, 'Vehicle Recovery', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=900, height=600, top=50, left='+left);

    });

    $('#all').on('click', function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        table.columns(23).search('').draw();
    });

    $('#active').on('click', function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        table.columns(23).search('').draw();
        table.columns(23).search('NO').draw();
    });

    $('#inactive').on('click', function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        table.columns(23).search('').draw();
        table.columns(23).search('YES').draw();
    });

    // Apply the search
    table.columns([2,3,4,5,7,8,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]).every( function () {
        var that = this;

        $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                that
                    .search('"'+ this.value+'"')
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );

})

$('#vehicle_modal').modal('show');
```

Comment: Have you put in debugging logs? Does the event handler occur when you expect it to? Do you reach the datatable initialization when the code fails? Do you have any error outputs in your log?

Comment: Yes. Yes. No errors. No code fails - it's just that the modal doesn't always fire before the datatables runs.